# First value after subscribing observable is always null

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular10

I have the following ProfileService:

```
export class ProfileService {
  private user: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);

  constructor(private userService: UserService) { 
    this.userService.getUser(1)
      .pipe(map((payload: Payload<Result>) => payload.result))
      .subscribe((User: user): this.user.next(user));
  }

  public getUser() : Observable<User> {
    return this.user.asObservable();
  } 
}
```

On a few components I inject the `AuthorizationService` and call the `authorize` method:

```
export class AuthorizationService {

  user$: Observable<User>;

  constructor(private profileService: ProfileService) { 
    this.user$ = this.profileService.getUser();
  }

  authorize(policy: Policy, data: any) : Observable<boolean> {

    this.user$.subscribe(x => console.log(x)); // PROBLEM HERE
    // Remaing code

  }

}
```

**Problem**
The first time I use `console.log` in `authorize` I always get `null` for `user$`

Any idea why?

Comment: Sounds like you might have a race condition issue; assuming `getUser()` is async, by the time you `console.log`, the call hasn't yet finished, which is probably why you have a null value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a `BehviourSubject` which you initialize with `null` which will then always be the first emission. If you want to prevent that, use a regular `Subject` instead:

`private user = new Subject<User>();`

This will emit whenever `next` is being called on it.

Or `ReplaySubject`

`private user = new ReplaySubject<User>(1);`

by initializing it with `1` it will store the last value and emit that when subscribed to.

Note: with both of these you will lose the ability to access `.value` and `.getValue()`